# Auto generate meta description for impoted products

Tags: magento-1.9

I've create a module for Auto generate of meta description but it's not workin for imported products but i want this also work for imported product and I am using an extension instead of Magento's default import/Export.

`app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Easylife_Meta>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Easylife_Meta>
</modules>
<global>
<models>
<easylife_meta>
<class>Easylife_Meta_Model</class>
</easylife_meta>
</models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
<events>
<catalog_product_save_before><!-- observe the event -->
<observers>
<easylife_meta>
<class>easylife_meta/observer</class>
<method>autoMetaDescription</method>
</easylife_meta>
</observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
</events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Meta/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php 
class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer {
public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

$meta_description = $product->getMetaDescription();
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();

if ($meta_description == '' || $meta_description == null)
{

if($attributeSetName == "Books"){
$publisher_attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('publisher');
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at booksnclicks.com | Buy New Book | Authorised seller for ".$publisher_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}



if($attributeSetName == "Gadgets"){
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at booksnclicks.com | Buy New Gadgets |Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('brand_gadgets');
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}

if($attributeSetName == "Stationery"){
$metaDescription = "Buy ". $product->getName()." for Rs ".number_format($product->getFinalPrice(), 2)." at sbooksnclicks.com | Buy New Stationery | Authorised seller for ". $product->getAttributeText('brand_stationery');
$product->setMetaDescription($metaDescription);
}

}

} 
}
```

Comment: What kind of import extension are you using? Magmi perhaps?

Comment: The event you are using is working only when saving the product via an admin or when calling `$product->save()`. My suggestion is not to modify the import process. Instead just write a script that processes your csv and fills in the meta description field. Then use the generated csv in the import process.

Comment: @Marius i am thinking that to create a module to auto generate meta description when we Reindex data

Comment: I think you are over engineering it. you already have some code that it works when you save a product in the backend. You only need something that will transform your csv and fill in the meta description before using that file for import. An other simple idea would be just to rewrite the product model and add a method called `getMetaDescription`  where you can simply return your text no matter what was filled in the the meta description field in the backend. Any of these approaches seams easier that what you are trying here.

Comment: @Marius thanks for suggestion,can you describe the second method(rewrite the product model) in detail how to do this

Comment: @Dinesh this explains it nicely: http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/